# $mysqli->info is null after successful insert of single row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

After inserting multiple rows with a single insert statement, I get expected behavior from $mysqli->info.

```
var_dump( $mysqli->info );
string 'Records: 1246  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0' (length=41)
```

After inserting a single row, $mysqli->info returns NULL

```
var_dump( $mysqli->info );
null
var_dump( $mysqli->affected_rows );
int 1
```

mysqli_info() returns an empty string

```
var_dump( mysqli_info( $mysqli ) )
string '' (length=0)
```

I cannot find any reference to this behavior! I would expect info after a single insert like

```
string 'Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0' (length=38)
```

PHP 5.4.12, mySQL 5.6.12

Executed Code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO module_history (BackupDate, Modules) VALUES ('2014-01-01','Module List1')";
$db->query($sql);
echo $sql . "\n";
var_dump( $db->info );
var_dump( $db->affected_rows );

$sql = "INSERT INTO module_history (BackupDate, Modules) VALUES ('2014-01-02','Module List2'),('2014-01-03','Module List3')";
$db->query($sql);
echo $sql . "\n";
var_dump( $db->info );
var_dump( $db->affected_rows );
```

Results:

```
INSERT INTO module_history (BackupDate, Modules) VALUES ('2014-01-01','Module List1')
null
int 1
INSERT INTO module_history (BackupDate, Modules) VALUES ('2014-01-02','Module List2'),('2014-01-03','Module List3')
string 'Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0' (length=38)
int 2
```

Comment: Why don't you post *complete code* that you *actually* runs?

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44270 but for `5.2.5 `

Comment: I can confirm the behavior for the recent 5.5.9. Why do you need that string anyway?

Comment: Because I am actually using INSERT IGNORE in some cases, and I would like to know how many records I attempted to insert vs how many were actually inserted. Specifically the Duplicates information.

Comment: The bug mentions that a single row insert is not a supported situation, but I cannot find any documentation as to what IS a supported situation.

Comment: @Kenneth you can always answer your own questions. It seems the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.info.html

### Table 3.9 Possible mysqli_info return values

**Query Type - Example result string**

- INSERT INTO...SELECT... Records: 100 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0
- INSERT INTO...VALUES (...),(...),(...)   Records: 3 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0
- LOAD DATA INFILE ... Records: 1 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 0 Warnings: 0
- ALTER TABLE ...  Records: 3 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0
- UPDATE ...   Rows matched: 40 Changed: 40 Warnings: 0

**Note**

Queries which do not fall into one of the preceding formats are not supported. In these situations, mysqli_info will return an empty string.

---

**Conclusion:** There is not a case listed above for a single row insert. Therefore, an empty string is what should be expected.

Comment: OK. I spent two hours debugging and THIS is the answer to why ->info returns an empty string? Whoever thought this might be acceptable behaviour for ->info should be condemned to eternal minecraft.